# I need to find possible values of latitude and longitude around a geometric position( with known distance )

Tags: geometry

[image http://zoyabean.com/geo.png](http://zoyabean.com/geo.png)
How to find $[ latx1 , lonx1 ] , [ latx2 , lonx2 ] , [ latx3 , lonx3 ] , [ latx4 , lonx4 ]$ using $lat1$ , $lon1$ and $d$ from the image. ( $lat1$ and $lon1$ are in degree and  $d$ in Km )

---

### OR

---

This is the equation for finding the distance between 2 points in earth surface.

$R = 6371$;    // Radious of earth

$lat_1 , lon_1$ ->   latitude and longitude of first point ( in degree )

$lat_2 , lon_2$ ->   latitude and longitude of second point  ( in degree )

$d$ - >  distance b/w the two points ( in Km)

$dLat = (lat_2-lat_1)* (\pi/180)$;

$dLon = (lon_2-lon_1)* (\pi/180)$;

$$a = \sin^2\left(\frac{dLat}{2}\right) + \cos\left(lat_1*\frac{\pi}{180}\right)\cos\left(lat_2*\frac{\pi}{180}\right)\sin^2\left(\frac{dLon}{2}\right)$$

$$d = 2R\ \text{atan2}\left(\sqrt a, \sqrt{1-a}\right)$$

In tins equation  $lat_1$, $lon_1$, $d$ are known

I needed to find the possible values of $lat_2$ and $lon_2$.(  infinite values are possible but I just need [$latx1$,$lonx1$] [$latx2$,$lonx2$] [$latx3$,$lonx3$] [$latx4$,$lonx4$] )

Comment: Note: The earth is an oblate spheroid, not a sphere, and thus this will be off (IIRC worst case is up to 3%).

Comment: Convert distance to angle. (Latx2, Lonx2), (Latx4, Lonx4) are on the same longitude as (Lat1, Lon1), add/subtract the distance angle.